# C# 'cannot convert from 'char[]' to 'char*'

Tags: c#

I am having trouble in adding password credentials in a process using C#

Currently it looks as the following:

```
char[] passwordChars = {'x', 'x', 'x', '@', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'} ;
System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new SecureString(passwordChars, passwordChars.Length);
```

I am wondering how I go on about converting it to char* from char[].

Comment: *“This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.”* Use `AppendChar` repeatedly instead, probably. (The fact that you have `passwordChars` in an array already partly defeats the point of `SecureString`.)

Comment: Just a note that `SecureString` is no longer considered secure. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254774/how-to-remove-string-from-process-memory/44255219#comment75519234_44255219)

Answer (score 1):

Taken right from the [SecureString documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/176bafkd(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
System.Security.SecureString ssPwd;
char[] passwordChars = {'x', 'x', 'x', '@', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'} ;
fixed(char* pChars = passwordChars)
{
   ssPwd = new SecureString(pChars, chars.Length);
}


//Don't forget to dispose of your string after you're done with it:
ssPwd.Dispose();
```

Comment: I just tried it and got :

"Argument 1 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword"

Comment: See my updated code. You may need to wrap it in an `unsafe { }` context.

Comment: Hm, unsafe code to make a secure string. It sounds almost... poetic.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] passwordChars = { 'x', 'x', 'x', '@', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' };
System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new SecureString();
foreach (var c in passwordChars)
{
    ssPwd.AppendChar(c);
}
ssPwd.MakeReadOnly();
```