# How to protect password from getting stored in process dump MS word process c#

Tags: c#, winforms, security

While doing login to my windows application, the entered password text is getting stored in process dump file of MS Word process taken from the Windows Task manager. How can i prevent that from storing the password text in process dump file. (We have used Interop because we are doing operations on MS Word file)

For storing password - we used normal string class and then encrypting it and sending through API to DB.

**Please suggest.**

What we have tried :

> Encryption & decryption method we have tried. Although, while login process we still see the entered password text in process dump file.

Required Output :

We want to clear it out the password text from process dump file. 
Way of looking process dump file - go to task manager -> right click on process you are working on -> generate dump file -> open in text editor and we can do find option with entered password. Password will be present in process dump.  (For security reasons we need to remove password from process dump file.)

Comment: It's not quite clear, what's the relationship between your Windows Application and MS Word? When/Where is a password needed? Why/When do you need to store the password in process? Please elaborate a bit more. Meanwhile, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44255219/3110834).

Comment: Instead of using String class you should use SecureString , please see this link for further details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.8 . Also as mentioned by @RezaAghaei a better clarity on the use case and relationship between app and Word will allow a more appropriate input.

Comment: If you need to obscure the password, you can create a `hash` of it. Hash the entered password and validate by comparing the hash value with the hash value of the desired password. So you don't store the password in plain text but as a hash.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Reza, Soumen , Stefan

Comment: We have got the root cause which is Encoding.UTF8 was writing the plain text in memory dump. Please suggest if UTF7 or UTF32 should be useful here ?